# Some event fields won't sync

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider, icalendar

I have a calendar application that works well on any device. I can create new events, and these events sync with the server without any problem.
I also set "**CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE**" and "**CUSTOM_APP_URI**" fields that work well on the device. But when I use the same account on another device, I get ***null*** value for these fields. 
I have already read the [CalendarContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns#CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE) documentation. These fields are supposed to sync without using a sync adapter. Is there something I can do in code?

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, mCalendarTag.mID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName()); // **
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI, "myApp://a/b/c"); // **
mContentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: maybe an issue with permissions? I'm not familiar with this, but if it works on one device but not on another, maybe the app didn't request the proper permission to access the data there? For CalendarProvider it seems there are only a few permissions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#manifest

Comment: Can you tell the android version of both the devices?